# Implementing Classes in C

Tags: c

There is a constructor of person(class).
Why not

```
    pObj->pFirstName = pFirstName;
    pObj->pLastName = pLastName;
```

I don't understand the purpose of his writing like this.

```
pObj->pFirstName = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(pFirstName)+1));
if (pObj->pFirstName == NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}
strcpy(pObj->pFirstName, pFirstName);
```

Is there any difference between the two?
I didn't get it.
I didn't get it.
I didn't get it.
I didn't get it.
I didn't get it.

```
typedef struct _Person Person; //declaration of pointers to functions typedef void    (*fptrDisplayInfo)(Person*); typedef void    (*fptrWriteToFile)( Person*, constchar*); typedef void    (*fptrDelete)( Person *) ; typedef struct _Person  {
    char* pFName;
    char* pLName;
    //interface for function
    fptrDisplayInfo   Display;
    fptrWriteToFile   WriteToFile;
    fptrDelete      Delete; }Person;

Person* new_Person(const char* const pFirstName, 
                   const char* const pLastName); //constructor void delete_Person(Person* const pPersonObj);    //destructor void Person_DisplayInfo(Person* const pPersonObj); void Person_WriteToFile(Person* const pPersonObj, const char* pFileName);

person* new_Person(constchar* const pFirstName, constchar* const pLastName) {
    Person* pObj = NULL;
    //allocating memory
    pObj = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    if (pObj == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    pObj->pFirstName = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(pFirstName)+1));
    if (pObj->pFirstName == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(pObj->pFirstName, pFirstName);

    pObj->pLastName = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(pLastName)+1));
    if (pObj->pLastName == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(pObj->pLastName, pLastName);

    //Initializing interface for access to functions
    pObj->Delete = delete_Person;
    pObj->Display = Person_DisplayInfo;
    pObj->WriteToFile = Person_WriteToFile;

    return pObj; }
```

Comment: Unrelated: `sizeof(char)` is **always** `1`, so unclutter. More keystrokes != better code.

Comment: I suggest you read up on Stack vs Heap allocation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version sets one pointer to another pointer. The End.

The second version allocates and makes a duplicate copy of the C-style string referenced by one pointer, into another memory buffer, and then sets the second pointer to point to it.

There are many reasons for doing that, that are tied directly with classes, and the concept of ownership.

In the first case, if whatever memory the original pointer was pointing to gets freed/destroyed, dereferencing the now-invalid pointer becomes undefined behavior.

In the second case, the class has its own copy of the original text string, that's still valid. Of course, to avoid leaking memory, when the class instance gets destroyed it should also destroy the memory buffer it originally allocated. You should see this happening in whatever code is responsible for destroying an instance of this class.

Answer (score 1):

If you just assign the pointers, then the structure contains a pointer to the caller's string. If the caller's string goes out of scope, or the caller frees it, the pointer will no longer be valid. And if they modify their string, it will also modify the string in the structure.

Making a copy of the string ensures that it is not dependent on the caller's string once it's put into the structure.

Answer (score 0):

The first only does a shallow copy of pFirstName, / pLastName

The second does a hard copy.  -- It allocates another copy on heap.